# Databinding with external URLs using server side rendering

Tags: javascript, angular, server-side-rendering

I'm building an angular SSR application. Theres a simple problem Im having that someone may be able to solve.

It seems that when I data bind a url to an `<a>` tag, it appends that url to the end of my applications home url.

Example: 
`<a [href]="url">Link</a>` in my home.component.html file.

url = "www.google.com"; in home.component.ts file.

If you implement SSR, this url will direct you to "www.my-app.com/www.google.com" instead of "www.google.com".

I've tried a basic test and it seems to be this way. How do I direct to external urls without window (due to SSR)? Is there a way to do so in the template when Im data binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried adding 'http://' to the beginning of URL?

Comment: Trying now. Will let you know

Comment: Ah. That was it. How simple : D. Thanks